# catch only memory issues C++

Tags: c++, class, exception, memory

What is the exception type I can catch to detect any memory issues?

I want to detect when `new` fails, or `c'tor` of class fails.

`catch (Exception &e)` is too broad and doesn't only catch memory issues.

Note: I remember there was such a type but forgot it, it starts with `std::`

Comment: When a constructor fails, its up to the class to decide what it throws. There is no generic "failed constructor" exception.

Comment: When `new` fails **because it couldn't allocate memory** it will throw [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc). It can fail for other reasons, and there is no standard exception type for that.

Comment: There is no base `Exception` type. You may be thinking of `std::exception`. This is the base for any standard exception type, and it may be the base for third party exceptions, but it is not guaranteed to catch all exceptions.

Comment: @drescherjm so to catch ALLOCATION_ERROR I need to catch everything

Comment: @whiteforce No, drescherjm 's comment is telling you which specific error you need to catch.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux let's say I was asked to catch ALLOCATION_ERROR so that will be using std::exception

Comment: @whiteforce `ALLOCATION_ERROR` is not something standard. I don't know what it means.

Comment: But he told me that sometimes not this error gets returned

Comment: I was told to catch in case allocation faild, so which to catch?

Comment: @whiteforce Hello, I have provided an answer which hopefully clarifies this concern. Please upvote and click the accept button if your question is resolved.

Comment: Your OS may just kill your application in a low memory situation or it could cause your OS to become rather unresponsive.

Comment: The code you added completely changes the question. And it raises many, many questions about what it is intended to do, and about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `b1 = static_cast<b_platform *>(DS);` can't possibly `throw` so the `catch` can't possibly happen. This is the reason for the warning. There are no allocations in this code, so it is not clear how the code related to your question about failure to allocate.

Comment: … presumably the allocation happens inside `add_course`. But that `void *DS` is a really big red flag. I really hope that you are not using this to learn C++.

Answer (score 3):

Running out of memory throws `std::bad_alloc`, *if* the operating system chooses to report the problem to the application.

Constructors can do more than allocate memory, and they can throw whatever they want.

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) is an overview of all the standard exception classes.

Answer (score 1):

If `new` fails because it itself is not able to allocate memory for the new object prior to calling the object's constructor, it will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

If memory for the object is allocated successfully, and then the constructor throws its own exception for any reason, `new` will cancel the construction, free the memory it was able to allocate, and re-throw whatever exception the constructor threw.

Unless you use the `nothrow` version of `new`, in which case it will silently discard any exception thrown and return a `nullptr` instead.